# What is the best way for reducer size optimization in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to pig, working on a script where I am facing a situation. My job runs quite efficiently for majority of reducers but last few reducers takes hours to complete. The only plausible explanation I could come up with is that few reducers are having a large number of data, which is quite possible as I have to a join on a dataset with over 10 million rows to a one with approx 500 rows as a mapping exercise.

The 2 ways which I found are setting number of reducers by using parallel and other is using `pig.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer`.

Which of the methods will be better in my case? (there might be huge number of records mapped to a single key).

Also, for `pig.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` what is the correct method of implementation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is nice doc on tuning map-reduce job :-
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/07/how-to-tune-mapreduce-parallelism-in-apache-pig-jobs/

As you also guessed it seems to be data skewness problem - few keys have high number of records then other.

If one of your file is small and can easily fit into memory try using replicated join. This is mapper side join and normally it takes care of data skewness problem

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helps

Answer (score 0):

For optimizing the join you should use replicated join as

```
 C = JOIN big BY b1, tiny BY t1, mini BY m1 USING 'replicated';
```

and to process your job in parallel or increase the number of reducer for all steps you can just add a line

```
  SET default parallel 100;
```

at the start of the pig script or you can use the

```
parallel 100; //on the line of the code
```